# Invoke remote webservice from within asp.net webapi

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a new asp.net MVC4 Web API (webapi) application that I'm working on and most if is working fine. One of the last tasks is to take bank account info and charge the user a given amount. I have already worked out how to get the users info with a typical POST method and some JSON. We use a webservice from a credit card processor to actually charge the customer however. In our current asp.net web forms app I simply added the webservice using the web reference tool in vs2012 and everything works fine. My problem is how do i do this in mvc4 webapi. There is no web reference option, only a service reference which does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the web API. "Add Web Reference" is the old way to access a SOAP web service. Use "Add Service Reference" instead.

Comment: Agreed, And I did add the service reference. VS seems to have added it, however, I have no idea how to utilize or invoke or call the service reference from within a class.